# Vue JS - Problem with incrementing value by one in parent component using $emit

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am learning **$emit** in Vue JS, I decided to create a value called `counter` in the child component then increment by one when the button is clicked, but I decided to write all the logic in the parent component using **$emit**

But every time I click on the button, the value does not increase although the method works

[image]

**LifeCycles.vue**

```
<template>
    <div>
        <p>{{counter}}</p>
        <button @click="add">Click me</button>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      counter: 0,
    };
  },

  methods: {
      add() {
        this.$emit('updated', this.counter)
      }
  },
};
</script>
```

**HeadlineLifeCycle.vue**

```
<template>
  <div>
      <LifeCycles @updated="usefulMethod" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import LifeCycles from "./LifeCycles.vue";
export default {
  components: {
    LifeCycles,
  },

  methods: {
     usefulMethod: function(counter) {
        console.log(counter++)
     }
  }
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line

```
this.$emit('updated', this.counter)
```

is not emitting `this.counter` reference, so any time you click on the button, you actually are emmiting the counter initial value which is `0`.
So, if you really need to do all the logic in the parent component, you have to define the `counter` variable in parent component:

**lifecycle.vue**

```js
<template>
    <div>
        <p>{{counter}}</p>
        <button @click="$emit('clicked')">Click me</button>
    </div>
</template>
```

**HeadlineLifeCycle.vue**

```js
<template>
  <div>
      <LifeCycles @clicked="increase" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import LifeCycles from "./LifeCycles.vue";
export default {
  components: {
    LifeCycles,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      counter: 0,
    };
  },
  methods: {
     increase: function() {
        console.log(this.counter++)
     }
  }
};
</script>
```

---

You also can pass a variable to the lifecycle.vue as `model` and manage its value  in `lifecycle` component.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you're not incrementing `count` in the child component where it's placed in its `data`:

```js
const lifecycles = Vue.component('lifecycles', {
  template: "#lifecycles",
  data() { return { counter: 0 } },
  methods: {
    add() { this.$emit('updated', ++this.counter); } // fix
  }
});

new Vue({
  el: "#headlinelifecycle",
  components: { lifecycles },
  methods: {
    usefulMethod: function(counter) { console.log(counter); }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<template id="lifecycles">
    <div>
        <p>{{counter}}</p>
        <button @click="add">Click me</button>
    </div>
</template>

<div id="headlinelifecycle"><LifeCycles @updated="usefulMethod" /></div>
```

If you want to control `LifeCycles` from the parent state:

```js
const lifecycles = Vue.component('lifecycles', {
  template: "#lifecycles",
  props: ['counter'],
  methods: {
    add() { this.$emit('updated', this.counter+1); } 
  }
});

new Vue({
  el: "#headlinelifecycle",
  components: { lifecycles },
  data() { return { counter: 0 } },
  methods: {
    usefulMethod: function(counter) {
      this.counter = counter;
      console.log(this.counter); 
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<template id="lifecycles">
    <div>
        <p>{{counter}}</p>
        <button @click="add">Click me</button>
    </div>
</template>

<div id="headlinelifecycle">
    <LifeCycles @updated="usefulMethod" :counter="counter" />
</div>
```